# parameter of a misunderstood function

Tags: c++, openssl

here is the problematic function:

```
EVP_PKEY_CTX *EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(int id, ENGINE *e);
```

In fact I don't understand the value of the id in the function, how to get this variable ...
Can you help me please?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: the documentation says:  The EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id() function allocates public key algorithm context using the algorithm specified by id and ENGINE e. It is normally used when no EVP_PKEY structure is associated with the operations, for example during parameter generation of key generation for some algorithms.

Comment: The `id` can be understood like a name (identifier) to identify a created instance afterwards by something else than the pointer and to distinguish multiple instances. Using an `int` instead of a string might have been done for performance reasons. Although a name (in a string) might be more intuitive, an `int` identifier is easier to store and to process internally. I assume you have to ensure that multiple calls have to use distinct values, in the simplest case, a variable which is incremented after each call.